# Deducing linear conjugacy from conjugacy of linear systems

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives, linear-transformations, frechet-derivative

Given $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a $C^1$ surjective diffeomorphism $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, suppose that $e^{tX} \circ F = F \circ e^{tY}$ for all real $t \in [0, \infty)$. I wish to verify that there exists an invertible matrix $M$ such that $MA = BM$.

To begin, I noticed that $F(0) = 0$ need not hold. So, let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $F(0) = a$. However, $G(x) = F(x) - a$ should also satisfy the same conditions that $F$ does. It is clear that $G$ is $C^1$ diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n$. **Unfortunately, it is not clear to me that $e^{tX} \circ G = G \circ e^{tY}$. I have tried**
\begin{align*} 
 G \circ e^{tY}(x)
 &= (F - a) \circ e^{tY}(x) \\
 &= F \circ e^{tY}(x) - a \\
 &= e^{tX} \circ F(x) - a \\
 &= e^{tX} \circ G(x) & (\text{This is the questionable step.})
 \end{align*}
By taking $t = 0$ at the end, this would then allow us to obtain
\begin{align*}
 D(G \circ e^{tY}) De^{tY} = D(e^{tX} \circ G) DG
 &\implies D(G \circ e^{tY})(0) De^{tY}(0) = D(e^{tX} \circ G)(0) DG(0) \\
 &\implies DG(0) e^{tY} = e^{tX} DG(0) \\
 &\implies \frac{d}{dt} \left(D(G)(0) e^{tY}\right) = \frac{d}{dt} \left(e^{tX} DG(0)\right) \\
 &\implies DG(0) Y e^{tY} = Xe^{tX} DG(0) \\
 &\implies DG(0) Y = X DG(0).
 \end{align*}
The invertibility of $DF$ then allows us to conclude that $DG(0)$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this a little more closely. The equality holds; the steps are shown below:
\begin{align*} 
 G \circ e^{tY}(x)
 &= (F - a) \circ e^{tY}(x) \\
 &= F \circ e^{tY}(x) - a \\
 &= F \circ e^{tY}(x) - F(0) \\
 &= F \circ e^{tY}(x) - F \circ e^{tY}(0) \\
 &= e^{tX} \circ F(x) - e^{tX} \circ F(0) \\
 &= e^{tX} \circ (F(x) - a) \\
    &= e^{tX} \circ G(x) \\
\end{align*}